# lshw output: unclaimed and strange lines in memory

Tags: drivers, hardware, battery

I am sorry if this has already been asked, I could not find any solutions. I have some questions about *lshw* output:
1. What do these lines in *memory section mean? (the same appears in *-bank:1 and *-bank:3)

```
*-bank:0
         description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-02 13:04+0000Last-Translator: Joel Addison <jaddi27@gmail.com>Language-Team: English (Australia) <en_AU@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2015-02-19 11:31+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 17341) [empty]
         physical id: 0
         slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
```

2. What does UNCLAIMED mean in the following section? Can it somehow be the reason the battery is draining so fast?

```
*-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:e0618000-e06180ff ioport:efa0(size=32)

*-power UNCLAIMED
   description: TBD by ODM
   product: TBD by ODM
   vendor: TBD by ODM
   physical id: 2
   version: 1.0
   serial: TBD by ODM
   capacity: 32768mWh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line looks like a translation error message.  Try running `LANG=C lshw` and see if it goes away.  The second one is simply saying that your motherboard has an I2C controller that no driver has claimed, which is normal since it is just used by the BIOS to identify what kind of DIMMs you have installed.  The third appears to be a power supply that your vendor did not properly fill in the descriptions for.  I'm not sure why that is unclaimed, but it wouldn't cause any extra power draw.

Comment: I tried `LANG=C lshw` and now there is: 
`*-bank:0
             description: DIMM [empty]`
should it be 'empty'?

Comment: @DariaIsNotHere, so only bank 2 says it is populated?  Do you only have a single DIMM installed?

Comment: the output of `dmidecode` shows only one and it is marked as 'bank2'. So, everything is okay, right?
One more thing, about those 'UNCLAIMED' lines. I just leave all as it is? They are not causing any trouble, are they?

Comment: @DariaIsNotHere, yes, everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

2. 'UNCLAIMED' simply means that the kernel has no driver associated with this device.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu bug [#1597886](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lshw/+bug/1597886) was filed for this in 2016 and it was fixed earlier this year (2020).

[The fix](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/459702289/0001-dmi-do-not-provide-gettext-with-an-empty-string.patch) consists of adding precisely one white space to otherwise empty strings in the `lshw` source code.

```
diff --git a/src/core/dmi.cc b/src/core/dmi.cc
@@ -495,9 +495,9 @@ static const char *dmi_memory_array_location(u8 num)
 {
   static const char *memory_array_location[] =
   {
-    "",                                           /* 0x00 */
-    "",
-    "",
+    " ",                                           /* 0x00 */
+    " ",
+    " ",
     N_("System board or motherboard"),
     N_("ISA add-on card"),
     N_("EISA add-on card"),
[...]
```